# Error in using OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am making an app that shows map offline . So I use OSM but first of all I want to make a simple app via OSM to undrestand how it work , unfortunately when I ran it ,give me some errors .
I made another app that shows map via google map and I know how can I work with maps already , but I don't know how can I work with OSM and make an app via it ,very well.

Also I have two questions about it:

I don't know , for developing a map via OSM , I had to extend a class or implement some interface ?
also I don't know for working with OSM , I must use API key like working with google map and google API?

here is my MainActivity class ...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MapView myOpenMapView;
private MapController myMapController;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myOpenMapView = new MapView(this, 256);
    myOpenMapView.setClickable(true);
    myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    setContentView(myOpenMapView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<org.andnav.osm.views.OpenStreetMapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/osm_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    cloudmadeStyle="1"
    renderer="CloudMadeStandardTiles"
    android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.osmsample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.osmsample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

please guide me...
thanks...

Comment: This request is hardly tied to the Andnav libs, so I suggest to ask over there, as here are only very few people with this special interest.

Comment: I use two jar file as lib in my app .Its name are "osmandroid-android","slf4j-android"... Do you mean them?